# How to INSERT INTO [temp table] FROM [Stored Procedure] and Select * FROM [temp table]

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have something like

```
Create TABLE #members
(   
    [member_id] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [registration_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [date_modified] [datetime] NULL,
    [date_created] [datetime] NULL
)
INSERT #members
(
    [member_id],
    [registration_id],
    [date_modified],
    [date_created]
)
EXEC
dbo._roster_member_GetMemberContacts_byMember_id @Member_id = 1000
Select * from #members
```

when I run it in query analyzer window:
There is already an object named '#members' in the database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Query Analyzer, unless you explicitly `DROP` the temporary table, the temporary table will exist for the life of the Query Analyzer window.

Comment: @FiveTools -- that's weird.  Without having the SP code, it's hard to say what's going on, but using a stub for the SP, your code works fine for me.  What version of SQL are you using?

Comment: Also, what happens when you simply execute the `DROP TABLE` command, then try re-running everything?  It's possible the code had an error at some point and didn't run `DROP TABLE` as the last line of code.

Comment: closed out the active window and started fresh.  worked!  accepted as answer.

Answer (score 3):

Use the following idiom:

```
if object_id('tempdb..#temptable', 'U') is not null
    drop table #temptable
create table #temptable ( ... )
... rest of SQL ...
```

Obviously substituting the name of your temp table.